# go-swagger with path param

Tags: go, swagger

Route:

```
// swagger:route DELETE /v1/path/{id} api DeleteV1
//
// Deletes an item.
//
//     Schemes: https
//
//     Responses:
//       202: AcceptedResponse
//       401: UnauthorizedErrorResponse
//       500: InternalServerErrorResponse
"/v1/path/{id}": {
    "DELETE":  Handle(DeleteRequest{}),
    "OPTIONS": s.handleOptionsRequest,
},
```

Params/response model:

```
// Description
//
// swagger:parameters DeleteV1
type DeleteRequest struct {
    // id of an item
    //
    // In: path
    id string `json:"id"`

    cookies  []*http.Cookie
}

// Description
//
// swagger:response DeleteResponse
type DeleteResponse struct {
}
```

I keep getting `- path param "{id}" has no parameter definition` whatever I try.

The endpoint takes only path param "id", cookies (they are not visible in a swagger model) and returns an empty body and an HTTP status code.

How to make go-swagger see the "parameter definition"for the "{id}"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The struct field needs to be exported.  Try:

```
type DeleteRequest struct {
    // ID of an item
    //
    // In: path
    ID string `json:"id"`
```

Comment: @exebook: It follows the same rules as `encoding/json` for the json key. That is to say, it uses the field struct name by default, and that default can be overridden with the json tag. If you're using `{id}` in the path definition, then yes, the json tag is probably necessary.  If you use `{ID}` in the path definition, then no json tag would be necessary. I would tend toward `{ID}` in the path in my own code, but you can of course use it however you want.

Comment: that would be great to have in the answer